# Adwords old conversion label is appearing again

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I am using Google tag manager for Adwords conversion tracking. **9 months ago**, I changed the conversion labels (earlier there was one for all properties, now different labels for different properties).

However, the old label still appearing with very high (impossible) conversion values.

How is this possible?

Plus, non of these transactions (transactions with old label) are recorded on Google Analytics. I tried to trace them comparing revenue values.

Any word on this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you sure that conversion code not installed in GTM it means adwords conversion code installed on site, maybe on wrong page, if this is not real conversions.

Comment: Thank you Ruslan, I'll check that :) :) that could be the reason